# Difference between thenAccept and thenApply

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I'm reading the document on `CompletableFuture` and The description for `thenAccept()` is

> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed with this stage's result as the argument to the supplied action.

and for `thenApply()` is

> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed with this stage's result as the argument to the supplied function.```

Can anyone explain the difference between the two with some simple examples?

Answer (score 59):

You need to look at the full method signatures:

```
CompletableFuture<Void>     thenAccept(Consumer<? super T> action)
<U> CompletableFuture<U>    thenApply(Function<? super T,? extends U> fn)
```

`thenAccept` takes a `Consumer` and returns a `T=Void` CF, i.e. one that does not carry a value, only the completion state.

`thenApply` on the other hand takes a `Function` and returns a CF carrying the return value of the function.

Comment: If we take it as compare to Stream,  thenAccept() is some what similar to forEach (Consumer ) and theApply  is similar to map (Function)

Comment: but why does this function exist? just for the sake of not returning anything? I think `forEach()` has to exist cuz the overhead of array in `map()` is quite significant, however that doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 40):

`thenApply` returns result of curent stage whereas `thenAccept` does not.

Read this article: http://codeflex.co/java-multithreading-completablefuture-explained/

[image: CompletableFuture methods]

Answer (score 26):

As **the8472** clearly explained, they are differentiate by their output value and args and thus what you can do with them

```
CompletableFuture.completedFuture("FUTURE")
                    .thenApply(f -> f.toLowerCase())
                    .thenAccept(f -> System.out.println(f))
                    .thenAccept(f -> System.out.println(f))
                    .thenApply(f -> new String("FUTURE"))
                    .thenAccept(f -> System.out.println(f));
```

```
future
null
FUTURE
```

the *Apply* functions apply another function and pass a future holding a value

the *Accept* functions consume this value and returns future holding void

Answer (score 7):

I would answer this question in the way I remember the difference between the two:
Consider the following future.

```
CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello");
```

`ThenAccept` basically takes a consumer and passes it the result of the computation `CompletableFuture<Void>`

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = completableFuture
  .thenAccept(s -> System.out.println("Computation returned: " + s));
```

You can associate this with `forEach` in `streams` for easy remembering.

Where as `thenApply` accepts a `Function` instance, uses it to process the result and returns a Future that holds a value returned by a function:

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = completableFuture
  .thenApply(s -> s + " World");
```

You can associate this with `map` in the `streams` as it is actually performing a transformation.